# Get thread name in gdb

Tags: multithreading

In gdb when I gave command `info th`
I got the output like:

```
(gdb) info th
  5 Thread 0x7ffff3b54700 (LWP 1542)  0x00007ffff6705343 in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  4 Thread 0x7ffff2752700 (LWP 1544)  0x00007ffff670f163 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  3 Thread 0x7ffff3153700 (LWP 1543)  0x00007ffff670f163 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  2 Thread 0x7ffff4763700 (LWP 1541)  0x00007ffff69c7930 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
* 1 Thread 0x7ffff7fe17e0 (LWP 1520)  0x00007ffff66d2cdd in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I can conclude that there are 5 threads are running. But I can't get name of the function of the threads.

How can I get function name of the thread using gdb?

The thread 5 is paused its execution on `poll()`. But `poll()` is called by a function which is started by the thread. 
In my case I stated thread for `set_up_socket_to_listen()`. From where `'poll'` is called. I want to print `'set_up_socket_to_listen'`.

```
pthread_t l_thread; 
pthread_create(&l_thread, 0, (void *)&set_up_socket_to_listen, NULL);
```

I want to print `set_up_socket_to_listen` name

Comment: You seem to think that a thread is associated with one particular function. This is not the case, a thread can be running in any number of functions. The best you can do is get the *currently* executing function, which is precisely what gdb is showing you here.

Comment: I know that. But I just want to print the name of the function. Is it possible?

Comment: Of what function? It's clearly showing you that thread 5, for example, is currently executing `poll()` at this instant.

Comment: the thread is paused its execution on poll(). But poll() is called by a function which is started by the thread. 

In my case I stated thread for set_up_socket_to_listen(). From where 'poll' is called by some system function. I want to print 'set_up_socket_to_listen'.

pthread_t l_thread;
pthread_create(&l_thread, 0, (void *)&set_up_socket_to_listen, NULL);
I want to print 'set_up_socket_to_listen' name.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to get the thread's start routine from gdb. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9525623/119527) shows how to print several frames from the thread's call stack. Provided the call stack isn't very deep, you should be able to use this to determine the start routine for each thread. See also the [gdb docs for threads](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see thread 5:

```
(gdb) thread 5
(gdb) bt
```

will show you the call stack for that thread.